# PHP equivalent of Python's `urljoin`

Tags: php

What is the PHP equivalent for building a URL from a base URL and a potentially-relative path? Python provides [`urlparse.urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) but there does not seem to be any standard implementation in PHP.

The closest I've found is people suggesting the use of [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and then rebuilding the URL from parts, but implementations doing that generally get things like protocol-relative links wrong (for example, `//example.com/foo` turning into `http://example.com/foo` or `https://example.com/foo`, inheriting the base URL's protocol), and it also doesn't make it easy to handle things like parent directory links. Here are examples of those things working correctly in `urlparse.urljoin`:

```
>>> from urlparse import urljoin
>>> urljoin('http://example.com/some/directory/filepart', 'foo.jpg')
'http://example.com/some/directory/foo.jpg'
>>> urljoin('http://example.com/some/directory/', 'foo.jpg')
'http://example.com/some/directory/foo.jpg'
>>> urljoin('http://example.com/some/directory/', '../foo.jpg')
'http://example.com/some/foo.jpg'
>>> urljoin('http://example.com/some/directory/', '/foo.jpg')
'http://example.com/foo.jpg'
>>> urljoin('http://example.com/some/directory/', '//images.example.com/bar.jpg')
'http://images.example.com/bar.jpg'
>>> urljoin('https://example.com/some/directory/', '//images.example.com/bar.jpg')
'https://images.example.com/bar.jpg'
>>> urljoin('ftp://example.com/some/directory/', '//images.example.com/bar.jpg') 
'ftp://images.example.com/bar.jpg'
>>> urljoin('http://example.com:8080/some/directory/', '//images.example.com/bar.jpg')
'http://images.example.com/bar.jpg'
```

Is there an idiomatic way of achieving the same in PHP, or a well-regarded simple library or implementation that actually gets all of these cases correct?

Comment: I belive you will have to make it

Comment: @RyanVincent I still don't see anything there that's doing anything more than just `parse_url` in a more OO way. Relative path concatenation is way more complicated than just replacing URL parts willy-nilly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is clearly a need for this functionality and none of the random scripts out there cover all the bases, I've started a [project on Github](https://github.com/plaidfluff/php-urljoin) to try to do it right.

The implementation of `urljoin()` is currently as follows:

```
function urljoin($base, $rel) {
    $pbase = parse_url($base);
    $prel = parse_url($rel);

    $merged = array_merge($pbase, $prel);
    if ($prel['path'][0] != '/') {
        // Relative path
        $dir = preg_replace('@/[^/]*$@', '', $pbase['path']);
        $merged['path'] = $dir . '/' . $prel['path'];
    }

    // Get the path components, and remove the initial empty one
    $pathParts = explode('/', $merged['path']);
    array_shift($pathParts);

    $path = [];
    $prevPart = '';
    foreach ($pathParts as $part) {
        if ($part == '..' && count($path) > 0) {
            // Cancel out the parent directory (if there's a parent to cancel)
            $parent = array_pop($path);
            // But if it was also a parent directory, leave it in
            if ($parent == '..') {
                array_push($path, $parent);
                array_push($path, $part);
            }
        } else if ($prevPart != '' || ($part != '.' && $part != '')) {
            // Don't include empty or current-directory components
            if ($part == '.') {
                $part = '';
            }
            array_push($path, $part);
        }
        $prevPart = $part;
    }
    $merged['path'] = '/' . implode('/', $path);

    $ret = '';
    if (isset($merged['scheme'])) {
        $ret .= $merged['scheme'] . ':';
    }

    if (isset($merged['scheme']) || isset($merged['host'])) {
        $ret .= '//';
    }

    if (isset($prel['host'])) {
        $hostSource = $prel;
    } else {
        $hostSource = $pbase;
    }

    // username, password, and port are associated with the hostname, not merged
    if (isset($hostSource['host'])) {
        if (isset($hostSource['user'])) {
            $ret .= $hostSource['user'];
            if (isset($hostSource['pass'])) {
                $ret .= ':' . $hostSource['pass'];
            }
            $ret .= '@';
        }
        $ret .= $hostSource['host'];
        if (isset($hostSource['port'])) {
            $ret .= ':' . $hostSource['port'];
        }
    }

    if (isset($merged['path'])) {
        $ret .= $merged['path'];
    }

    if (isset($prel['query'])) {
        $ret .= '?' . $prel['query'];
    }

    if (isset($prel['fragment'])) {
        $ret .= '#' . $prel['fragment'];
    }


    return $ret;
}
```

This function will correctly handle users, passwords, port numbers, query strings, anchors, and even `file:///` URLs (which seems to be a common defect in existing functions of this type).

Comment: Because of the common need for this I went ahead and just made a github project: https://github.com/plaidfluff/php-urljoin